# Is there a system of knowing where secret entrances are besides shooting all the walls?

Tags: enter-the-gungeon

My current strategy is to shoot all walls in treasure rooms and if I haven't found a secret area yet I'll shoot the exit elevator walls. I'd say I find 1 secret entrance every 2 levels or so. Is there a better system?